# Syncing Monero blockchain and get error not sure that the problem is. Error posted below

Tags: blockchain, synchronization, error-log

I got this error all of a sudden, this is also my third time trying to sync the blockchain from scratch.

```
2017-07-01 02:37:30.764 [P2P7]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1004    [1;33m[167.114.166.199:55957 INC]  Synced 239998/1344461[0m
2017-07-01 02:37:33.263 [P2P3]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_protocol/cryptonote_protocol_handler.inl:1004    [1;33m[192.81.219.211:55014 INC]  Synced 240198/1344461[0m
2017-07-01 02:37:38.763 [P2P9]  ERROR   blockchain  src/cryptonote_core/blockchain.cpp:3383 Error adding block with hash: <d2655d92c4bb008650350bb60658f612297dde0685ebf4cb5735f4c261edfb15> to blockchain, what = Error adding spent key image to db transaction: MDB_PAGE_NOTFOUND: Requested page not found
2017-07-01 02:37:38.764 [P2P9]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:71   Failed to query m_blocks: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-07-01 02:37:40.152 [P2P9]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:71   DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-07-01 02:37:41.714 [P2P9]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:71   DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-07-01 02:37:41.834 [P2P9]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:71   DB error attempting to fetch block index from hashMDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-07-01 02:37:45.188 [P2P9]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:71   Failed to query m_blocks: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-07-01 02:37:47.176 [P2P9]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:71   Failed to query m_blocks: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
2017-07-01 02:37:48.896 [P2P9]  WARN    blockchain.db.lmdb  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:71   Failed to query m_blocks: MDB_BAD_TXN: Transaction must abort, has a child, or is invalid
```

Answer (score 3):

Your errors indicate that your blockchain is most likely corrupted. To resolve this issue you need to resync from scratch. This is done by deleting `data.mdb` from `C:\ProgramData\bitmonero\lmdb` (Windows) or `$HOME/.bitmonero/lmdb` (Linux and Mac OS X), which will trigger the resync.

To avoid corruptions make sure to always gracefully exit `monerod`. In addition, make sure you are running the latest version, which is 0.10.3.1 currently.

Comment: I'd test the RAM and HDD. Could be hardware failing if he tried 3 times without success. There was a case of bad RAM causing corruptions, if I rember well.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: give monero more disk space; restart it twice.

For me this was a full volume.   I had given Monero 20G last year, and now lmdb is bigger than that.  I was able to resize the volume and start monerod, which ran but did not write any new data.  After restarting monreod again, synchronization started correctly.

On the second restart I saw:

`2017-08-18 12:51:19.657     ...        INFO    global  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:571  [batch] DB resize needed
2017-08-18 12:51:19.662     ...        INFO    global  src/blockchain_db/lmdb/db_lmdb.cpp:487  LMDB Mapsize increased.  Old: 31744MiB, New: 32768MiB`

Perhaps restarting it caused a clean database close?  I was glad I did not have to resync the first 20GB of the blockchain.  Thanks devs who care about consistency!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same type of error! tried to resync the whole blockchain again, but the error wasn't solved. Maybe still isn't (guess problem is on my side)...

Anyway I get around by downloading the blockchain directly: [here](https://downloads.getmonero.org/blockchain.raw)
And importing it:

```
monero-blockchain-import --input-file blockchain.raw --resume=1
```

`--resume=1` to continue existing blockchain